# Best Practice for CSP with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-security-policy

My question is not about how to set up a CSP. I know that. I do however have a question about how others handle their CSP with Wordpress. Wordpress core includes inline styles and scripts, which is a pain to manage in a CSP as you need to get the SHA of the style/script and enter that into the CSP. Not only that, many (probably most) plugins and themes also included these which would require getting the SHAs of all those as well. Couple that with the fact that plugins are constantly updating and the core itself updates regularly this makes keeping the SHAs correct a maintenance nightmare. I could allow unsafe-inline ... but well ... unsafe! So, my question is what is a person to do with this? Does anyone out there have any wonderful tricks up their sleeves that automate the SHAs?

Comment: I am going to throw my 2 pennies in here .. And I know I'll get some negative feedback, but hey ..  Why WordPress if you're super concerned about security?  You're choosing the #1 attacked platform on the planet.   IF you're hosting plain page sites etc etc, I would not hesitate to use WP .. But when one is asking the questions you are, It's much like asking "How do I protect my Honda Civic when parked downtown Oakland"  --  #1 stolen car in America -- #1 place for stolen vehicles.  In short .. Don't park your Civic there, OR get a car that's harder to steal.

Comment: Sometimes, if the security you need is Kung Fu strong, you may need to build your own car!  --  Coming from the aspect of hosting over 300 WP sites myself, this is not a WP bash -- Just why place so much burden on yourself with security, when you can easily choose a more secure / obfuscated platform.

Comment: If you do your due diligence in which plugins you use and follow standard practices you can secure WordPress. I'm not super concerned about that part.

Answer (score 0):

Mee too I was surprised to see that close to none WP sites use a strict CSP.

My knowledge may be incomplete but:

- There is no way to get rid of inline scripts in Worpress since this is so deep in the core. So there remain hashes and nonces to enable a strict CSP with inline scripts.
- The plugin [no unsafe-inline](https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-unsafe-inline) will help you generate the nonces and hashes automatically. After generation it will help you tidying the list since after a change or update some may become obsolete while new ones need to be added.